# replace dataframe values with percentrank values from another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames. The first data frame has values between 0 and 1. 10 Rows (Person), 15 Columns (Variables). The second data frame gives me the Percent Rank Limits. First Row is 0% to 100% in 5%steps. What i would like to accomplish is (example) search the first value of the first column of `df1` in the column with the same name of `df2` and replace the value with the percent value of column1. The search algorism must be like If `df1value <= df2value` AND `df1value isnot <= df2value` (row+1) then `df1value = df2percentrank`. I am searching for help for hours and couldn't find any hint to a solution so unfortunately there is no code i can provide.

```
DF1:
V1|V2|V3
12|40|80

DF2:
PR|V1|V2|V3
0%|0|0|0|
50%|13|60|30
100%|60|100|70|

Output:
V1|V2|V3
0%|0%|100%
```

Comment: You will get much better help if you provide a minimal reproducible example of your input data and your expected output.

Comment: @AnandaMahto is right. Supply your data frames and what you expect to get as an output. You can use the dput command in R to create the underlying R-code for creating your data frames.

Comment: A quick glance at your description suggests that maybe you can look at `cut` + `merge` or `match` from base R, or the IRanges package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not the best way to do this, but it is what came to mind when I first saw the question:

```
setNames(data.frame(lapply(1:3, function(x) {
  cut(df1[[x]], c(df2[[x+1]], Inf), labels=df2[[1]])
})), names(df1))
#   V1 V2   V3
# 1 0% 0% 100%
```